# Constructing a Flower from Multiple Parts Texture Map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Anybody know the best way to make a flower out of this texture?  The texture has everything I need in terms of an alpha mask, glossiness, normal etc.  How would I construct the mesh from this?  Could I use one subdivided plane (to put all of the textures onto) and then cut out separate parts of the plane and retopolize the parts?  Or would I make multiple planes and then have their UV map align to a part of the image?  What're your guys' thoughts?[image]

Comment: Make the object with a shape that matches the shape of the reference image (you can use the image as background in the viewport ). Unwrap it from view, and edit the UV map so that it coincides with the part image you are going to use as texture.

Comment: Perfect.  And then due to the fact that I have an alpha mask, I don't need to match the shape exactly.  Is that right? @cegaton

Comment: it's up to you.